# ReadAsStringAsync can't get all records

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, console-application

I am trying to consume a webapi in a console app like below.

```
HttpResponseMessage rsp = await client.GetAsync("https://example.com/api/employees"); 
var responseString = await rsp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var outer = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OData<JArray>>(responseString);
```

I can just get 100 records from there. Acutally the outer.count should be way more than 100.

Comment: Sounds like the API probably implements paging, and you'll need to make multiple requests to get all the results.

Comment: Thanks Jon. if that is the case, how to get all records

Comment: Probably specific to the API. Check the docs\

Comment: Call the API directly from a browser - how many do you get then? If you only get 100 then it's clearly what the server is returning. My guess is as others have suggested, there is some kind of paging in the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of records returned depends on the internal implementation of the `HttpGet` method of the Web API service. If you can post the implementation of the `Get` method of the `EmployeesController`, then we can solve the question. There isn't much info here to say why you get less than the expected.

The call

`HttpResponseMessage rsp = await client.GetAsync("https://example.com/api/employees");`

Simply means that on the Web API service there is a method with the following "signature"

```
public IEnumerable<Employee> Get()
{
   // Dummy. Not returning IEnumerable<Employee>  exactly, only for illustration
   return employees;
}
```

Within this method, there could be a constraint to limit number of rows returned. E.g.

```
public IEnumerable<Employee> Get()
{
   // There could be such a constraint as illustrated below.
   // Note the Take(100), this is the constraint or restriction
   return employees.Where(x => x.Department == "HR").Take(100);
}
```

Finally, without seeing the code, no one can tell you why you are not getting the expected results. If you do not own the API then you would need to contact the party that owns the web api service you are consuming.